# Can I use a Godox V860 flash with the X1T wireless trigger?

Tags: flash, wireless-flash, godox

[image]

How do I use a trigger without a receiver? I use a Godox V860 flash.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Genereally, you can use any trigger all the time without a receiver - e.g. you can use your TV's remote control even in the kitchen, as there is nothing there that tells it that there is no receiver.

Comment: Maybe your flash has a built-in receiver (it is labelled as "wireless"). This [set on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Godox-High-Speed-Speedlite-Transmitter-Compatible/dp/B01E58RM4E/) seems to be made of your flash and your transmitter, so I assume they can work together without extra gear. Did you check the flash user's manual?

Comment: @xenoid the Mark I V860 andV850 have no built-in radio triggering. To use them with an X1T, the [XTR16S add-on receiver](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-xt16-2-4ghz-transmitter-receivers-released/) is needed, and you'd only get power control, HSS, and sync (no TTL).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is poorly worded but I assume you are asking if you can use the Godox X1T wireless trigger with your Godox V860 without attaching an external receiver. The answer is no. The Godox v860 does not have a built-in 2.4GHz receiver needed to communicate with the Godox X1T transmitter. To use it with the X1T, you need an XTR16S receiver attached to the flash's hot foot.

If you have the newer Godox V860 II, then yes, you can use it with the Godox X1T transmitter,  but you will need to read the manual and learn how to operate it.